# simplification of 2 if statements into a loop

Tags: javascript, algorithm, if-statement, simplify

I would like to simplify a code snippet where I have one main loop in which I put 2 if statements. The first if statement is about a test "`if (test1 or test2)`" and the second one is a test "`if (test1 and test2)`".

Curently, to differentiate them, I have to put at a higher level (but still in the main loop) another "if" (test on `diagExpression boolean`, see below); here's the code :

```
// Main loop 
  while (Hit.arrayCurrent[Hit.coordCurrent[0]+k][Hit.coordCurrent[1]+l] == Hit.currentPlayer[1]) 
  {   
   if (diagExpression)
     {   
      if ((a > b) || (b > c))
        return;
      else if (d)
       {   
        //do stuff1
       }   
     }   
  else
    {   
     if ((a > b) && (b > c))
        return;
     else if (d)
       {   
        //do stuff1
       }   
     }   
  }
```

I don't know how to do for simplifying this code snippet and avoiding to use the `stuff1` 2 times.

If anyone could see a solution.

**UPDATE :**

`diagExpression` is computed before the main loop :

```
// Boolean for 2 versions
  var diagExpression = false;

  if (Hit.direction == 'rightbottom')
    { 
      diagExpression = true;
      shift_x = 1;
      shift_y = 1;
      factor_x = 1;
      factor_y = 1;
      limit_x = 7;
      limit_y = 7;
    }
 else if (Hit.direction == 'left')
    {
      shift_x = -1;
      shift_y = 0;
      factor_x = -1;
      factor_y = 1;
      limit_x = 0;
      limit_y = -1;
    }

...

// Main loop 
  while (Hit.arrayCurrent[Hit.coordCurrent[0]+k][Hit.coordCurrent[1]+l] == Hit.currentPlayer[1])
```

I use different directions values into my code and this boolean is true if I have diagonal directions and false for vertical/horizontal directions.

Comment: your diagExpression please ..please make sure the code reads good..also tag the language used

Comment: diagExpression is a boolean wich is computed before the main loop. This is Javascript language

Comment: Put the two returns above. After both of them, so that only the code which has not returned executes it, write `if (d) //do stuff1`, just once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you could simplify your code so that you'd need to write the *stuff1* only once:

```
while (…) {   
  if (diagExpression) {  
    if ((a > b) || (b > c))
      return;
  } else {
    if ((a > b) && (b > c))
      return;
  }
  if (d) {
    // do stuff1
  }
}
```

or even

```
while (…) {   
  if (diagExpression ? (a > b) || (b > c) : (a > b) && (b > c)) {
    return;
  } else if (d) {
    // do stuff1
  }
}
```

and then you can get to the more advanced stuff, like

```
while (…) {   
  if ((a > b) + (b > c) >= 2 - diagExpression) {
    return;
  } else if (d) {
    // do stuff1
  }
}
```

though that gets rather unreadable, and might even be slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way :

```
if (diagExpression) {
     if ((a > b) || (b > c))
        return;
     if ((a > b) && (b > c))
        return;
}
if (d){   
     //do stuff1
}
```

This is what I believe @Daniel Daranas means as well.

Comment: Not exactly. You need an else for `if (diagExpression)` and put `if ((a > b) && (b > c))` there, just as the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34047143/96780) does. Otherwise you are changing the behaviour.